# Changing Matlab function from calling user listed files to call all files with same extension

Tags: matlab, function

I am working with this routine below that performs the specific M routine for all listed ascii files that I list as follows:

```
files={'file1name.asc', 'file2name.asc', 'fileNname.asc'};

ratios=NaN*zeros(1,length(files));
for i=1:length(files)
    ratios(i)=specific_m_routine(files{i}); 
end
```

How do I simply change this to call all .asc files in the directory, rather than listing each fileNname.asc?
Thanks!

Comment: `D = dir('*.asc')` would return a structure, in which you can access the name through `D(SomeIndex).name`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Uh, I'm not sure... What do you mean by, SomeIndex?  I just want it to process the data stored in the ascii files in the directory, regardless of their name. I'm looking for a way to avoid tediously typing each file in the directory by name, as the code requires currently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to pass a filename to your `specific_m_routine` function? If so, you need to use `dir` and `files(k).name` rather than listing all of your files in a cell array and referring to them with `files{k}`.

```
files = dir('*.asc');

ratios = nan(1, numel(files));

for k = 1:numel(files)
    ratios(k) = specific_m_routine(files(k).name); 
end
```

Or if you want to be able to use any directory.

```
folder = fullfile('path', 'to', 'data');

files = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.asc'));

ratios = nan(1, numel(files));

for k = 1:numel(files)
    ratios(k) = specific_m_routine(fullfile(folder, files(k).name));
end
```

This way will not require the files you're trying to load to be in the current directory.

As a side note, I feel like you have asked some variant of this exact question the past few days but haven't taken the time to digest the answers you have gotten. Please go back and review all of them to get a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I actually started a different routine than the one from the last few days.

Comment: @Svet There is a decent amount of overlap between projects, so take some time and study these sorts of things because you'll see them again!